# How to approximate the inverse of a large-scale sparse matrix in an efficient way?

Tags: performance, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

In my research, I am responsible to figure out the inverse of a large-scale (700 k * 700 k) sparse matrix. So how to do that efficiently?

The matrix has following properties:

1. large-scale(700 k * 700 k)
2. symmetric
3. Diagonally dominant
4. sparse

Comment: This is really a math, comp sci question rather than a code question.  You may want to ask in other groups too.

Comment: How badly do the obvious methods work? Eg. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.inv.html.